# ASP.net MVC problem in Controller managing a [HttpPost] : renders Layout and Page twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, redirect

I'm having an issue of RedirectToAction in an ASP.net MVC app

Explanation of what my app should do :

1. In the 'Home/AddItem' web page, the User enters text in a textbox (in a form)
2. User presses a 'Save' button
3. The 'AddItem' controller which is decorated with an [HttpPost] attribute  is triggered
4. In this controller, I save the populated model-object to my Web
   Service
5. I want to do a 'return RedirectoAction' to another controller,
   but it doesn't work :

   return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");

It actually renders the page on which the user was filling out the form. It leaves a couple of blank lines. Then I see a foreign string "Loading" and the page 'Home/Index' is rendered afterward.

And the URL in the Browser contains the URL to the former page (/Home/AddItem) not the one I'm expecting (/Home/Index)

[image: foreign string 'Loading' appears in the page]
[image: sketch of the problematic view inside a view]

I've tried to make my 'AddItem' controller return the 'AddItem' view, but same problem happens : the former page is at the top of the page and duplicate 'AddItem' page is appended to it !!

I've tried RedirectToURL, RedirectToRoute, etc.  to no avail !!
The only thing that makes the RedirectToAction("Home", "Index") works is by not rendering the 'AddItem' view into a Layout.  But this is not a solution for our project !!

Here are code snippets of my _ViewStart.cshtml page and of the 'AddItem' controller :

```
_ViewStart.cshtml

@{
    if (this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Login") {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml";
    }
    else {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
}

[Authorize]
  public ActionResult AddItem(DateTime? date) {
      if (!ValidateUserAuthentication(out User user)) {
          return Redirect("~/Login/Login");
      }

      ViewBag.CurrentDayOfWeek = myService.GetCurrentDayOfWeek();

      return View();
  }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItem(Transaction myTransaction) {

   // code that saves 'myTransaction' via my  Web Service

   // to make things simple, I return the 'AddItem' view
   // but it doesn't work : it appends a new view to the former view

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You appear to be making an ajax calls (ajax calls do not redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the JQuery mobile plugin interfered with the rendering of the new view.
Our frontend dev quickly replaced it with [Hammer.j](https://hammerjs.github.io/)s library and we're up and running. (We needed touch gestures implemented in our webapp)